# Is there a way to run scripts on physics collisions?

Tags: animation, scripting, physics

I want to run a physics simulation where certain things happen when objects collide --- for example, teleporting the object from one place to another, or spawning a new object.

I know that this should be possible by writing a Python script which advances one frame at a time, manually checking for interesting interactions on each frame and then updating the model. But that sounds like a shedload of code and also very slow and cumbersome.

Is there any way to, e.g., register callbacks which get executed when the physics engine detects collisions? This would allow me to play the animation normally and the interactions would fire along the way.

Comment: No there is no such automatic built-in callback. You have to code it yourself.